# Applescript - Extract specific text from edl

Tags: applescript

I’d like some help with an Applescipt that would extract specific text from an .edl 
Would like to extract the text that comes after `*FROM CLIP NAME: **SS0340_v102.MOV**` and copy this list of text into a new text document in the same location and named the same as the source document.

Original document:

```
TITLE:   MUP R1 EC V2.3 01-16 VFX 1-29
FCM: NON-DROP FRAME
000001  SS0340_V102.MOV                  V     C        00:00:00:03 00:00:06:13 01:04:44:18 01:04:51:04
*FROM CLIP NAME:  SS0340_V102.MOV
000002  US0020_V010.MOV                  V     C        00:00:00:03 00:00:05:15 01:10:36:13 01:10:42:01
*FROM CLIP NAME:  US0020_V010.MOV
```

New document:

```
SS0340_V102.MOV,
US0020_V010.MOV,
```

Comment: You want to overwrite the source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set inputFile to (choose file) as text
set outputFile to (POSIX path of (inputFile & "::") & "output.txt")
do shell script "grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]*MOV' " & quoted form of (inputFile's POSIX path) & " | sort -u > " & quoted form of outputFile
```

Comment: adayzdone - I have a follow up question: Your script pulls all instances of .mov in the file, so I'm ending up with duplicate filenames as there are multiple instances of the same filename. Can you add a command to remove duplicate filenames at the end of the script?

Comment: Try piping the results to sort -u

Comment: this helped me with my problem also, just would like to ask how the third line works or is there any sources you can share about 'do shell script?' i would really like to learn more about it. thanks!

Comment: This a good resource to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html